# windows phone 8 use webbrowser cookie in httpclient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

i am trying to get a Cookie out of the Webbrowser element in Windows phone 8 and then use that Cookie for a httpclient to connect to steamgifts.com.

```
previewbro.IsScriptEnabled = true;
previewbro.IsEnabled = true;
previewbro.Navigate(new Uri("https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamgifts.com%2F%3Flogin&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamgifts.com&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select"));
```

I use this to Login to Steam with a browser and get the Cookie. Then i try to give the Cookie to a httphandler:

```
        Uri adress = new Uri("http://www.steamgifts.com/");
        String html;
        HttpClientHandler handle = new HttpClientHandler();
        CookieCollection cookies;
        try
        {
            cookies = previewbro.GetCookies();
        }
        catch (Exception fehler1)
        {
            label.Text = fehler1.ToString();
            cookies = null;
        }
        try
        {
            if (cookies != null)
            {
                handle.CookieContainer.Add(adress, cookies);
                label.Text = "got cookies";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception fehler2)
        {
            label.Text = fehler2.ToString();

        }
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handle);

        var responsetask = client.GetAsync(adress);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await responsetask;
        html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        previewbro.NavigateToString(html);
```

The response i get still Shows i am not yet loged in.
any tips what i am missing/doing wrong?
or am i missunderstanding how it is supposed to work?